# How to get source/destination IP address of a packet in NS3 when I am using MacTx TraceSource for PointToPointNetDevice?

Tags: networking, header, simulation, ns-3

I am trying to simulate a fattree network in NS3. I have `UdpServerHelper` and `UdpClientHelper` to generate traffic between two hosts. Then I call

```
TraceConnectWithoutContext ("MacTx", MakeCallback (&SinkMethod))
```

on one of my NetDeviceContainer nodes and my `SinkMethod (Ptr<const Packet> pkt)` is successfully called. I can use `pkt->GetSize ()` to see the packet size but although I took a considerable amount of time browsing for the solution, I could not figure out how I can see the source and destination addresses of the packet since the header seems to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Headers on the Packets can either be Peek()ed or Remove()d. But, you can only the Peek() the top-most header, here a link-layer header, eg. PppHeader.

To access higher-layer headers, the preceding header must be removed first. Something along these lines should do the trick:

```cpp
static void
RxDrop(Ptr<const Packet> packet) {
    /* 
     * Need to copy packet since headers need to be removed
     * to be inspected. Alternatively, remove the headers,
     * and add them back.
     */
    Ptr<Packet> copy = packet->Copy();

    // Headers must be removed in the order they're present.
    PppHeader pppHeader;
    copy->RemoveHeader(pppHeader);
    Ipv4Header ipHeader;
    copy->RemoveHeader(ipHeader);

    std::cout << "Source IP: ";
    ipHeader.GetSource().Print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Destination IP: ";
    ipHeader.GetDestination().Print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sagar; Your answer really saved my time! I am new in Networking field and did not know there are multiple headers in NS3 packets. I wonder what is the best source to learn such things in NS3? (As I was searching for the solution to my question, I found some people had the same problem in google forums, and no one mentioned your answer there.)

Comment: @soroush I can definitely empathize: ns-3 has quite the learning curve. Unfortunately, I don't have a magic bullet, but I generally refer to the [tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.35/tutorial/html/index.html), [API documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.35/doxygen/index.html), and [ns-3-users Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users). As a last resort, you can refer to the ns-3 source code, but that's gonna take some time getting used to.

Comment: Also, just noting that having multiple headers on a packet is not specific to ns-3. That's is how networking works in general.